# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.slf4j.MDC

Tags: android, android-studio, slf4j

I've just upgraded to Android Studio v2.2.3, and have been battling to get my app rebuilt and run. I finally got it built, but when I try to debug it on a USB-connected device I get the error below (I'm using log4j in my app).

Has slf4j been superseded??

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.myspace.myname.myapp, PID: 1716
                  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.slf4j.MDC
                      at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LoggingEvent.getMDCPropertyMap(Unknown Source)
                      at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LoggingEvent.prepareForDeferredProcessing(Unknown Source)
                      at ch.qos.logback.core.OutputStreamAppender.subAppend(Unknown Source)
                      at ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender.subAppend(Unknown Source)
                      at ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender.subAppend(Unknown Source)
                      at ch.qos.logback.core.OutputStreamAppender.append(Unknown Source)
                      at ch.qos.logback.core.UnsynchronizedAppenderBase.doAppend(Unknown Source)
                      at ch.qos.logback.core.spi.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(Unknown Source)
                      at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.appendLoopOnAppenders(Unknown Source)
                      at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.callAppenders(Unknown Source)
                      at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.buildLoggingEventAndAppend(Unknown Source)
                      at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.filterAndLog_0_Or3Plus(Unknown Source)
                      at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.info(Unknown Source)
                      at com.myspace.myname.myapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:89)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/GAv4: Successfully bound to service but never got onServiceConnected callback
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
```

Comment: Have you found a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

The issue depends on how you're adding the dependency to your project.
For example:

a) You can let Gradle handle it for you:

```
 dependencies {
 compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-android:1.6.1-RC1'
 }
```

Or

b) You can download the JAR and add it to your libs folder and add the dependency to Gradle. I usually just add the entire tree to avoid having to add a "compile" line for each one:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
}
```